# In Javascript, how do you change the dom element in another document outside the current document?

Tags: javascript, onclick, markup

```
<button onClick="window.location.assign('guess01.php');window.location.href('gues01.php').querysSelector('#main').setAttribut('value','7')">
     Click
</button>
```

I'm trying to send the window to `page01` from `page02`. `page02` is where the button with the `onclick` event is. In the `onclick` event I'm trying to assign a value of 1 to the element with the id of main, and `#main` is on `page01`.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work, one way to do it could be that you use cookies or localStorage to set an attribute if you're on `page02`. On page01, read the attribute, if it exists, execute your JS to change whatever. Now when you leave page01, remove this stored key.

You could also have it as a get param in the URL and read from that.

Comment: Could you link me to a proper example? Thank you amply.